# openMP distribute loop iterations

Tags: c++, openmp

I am new in openMP. I am trying things to see how things work. I'd like to distribute loop iterations equally so that my output is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Not 11 22 33 or 1 3 2 1 3 2 4 5, etc. I've also tried reduction, but I do not think that's the right approach for this case.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nt, id) num_threads(2)
    {
        nt = omp_get_num_threads();  
        id = omp_get_thread_num();  

        //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        //#pragma omp atomic
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::cout << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If you run your loop sequentially, the output will be 0123456789. If you parallelize it, the order will become nondeterministic (e.g. 456012389).

Comment: With my #pragma omp parallel for, iterations are not distributed at all. For example, integer 2 is printed twice and are all the integers.

Answer (score 2):

Within a parallel region, you must use

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ...
    #pragma omp for
    for (...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

`#pragma omp parallel for` is a combined construct of a `parallel` and a `for`, which is not correct if you already are within a parallel region.

Note that the order is inherently non-deterministic. You can serialize with and `ordered` clause, but that usually defeats the purpose of doing things in parallel. See also this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029429/openmp-output-for-for-loop).

Also note that writing to streams in parallel can produce garbled output. If you must, protect the output with a `#pragma omp critical`.